# print results on screen of fuction js

Tags: javascript, printing

*I would like to print the results of the function shuffleA(array) on the screen. Why does the following attempt not work?

````
let startcountries = shuffleA(country);
console.log(startcountries);

function shuffleA(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i)
        const temp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[j]
        array[j] = temp
    }
    return array
}


const country= [
    { "code": "AF", "code3": "AFG", "name": "Afghanistan", "number": "004" },
    { "code": "AL", "code3": "ALB", "name": "Albania", "number": "008" },
    { "code": "DZ", "code3": "DZA", "name": "Algeria", "number": "012" },
    { "code": "AS", "code3": "ASM", "name": "American Samoa", "number": "016" }];```
````

Comment: Because the function `shuffleArray()` has not been used, nor is there any output to the screen whatsoever.

Comment: Please share the complete code

Comment: OK, you edited the question. You are directing your output to the console, not the screen. Use [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/0s4a7tbc/1/